# How to convert a hex code into char array in android

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make a String encrypted using the method **String->hex->base64->string**.

I want to convert the string to hex and hex to base64 and that to the initial string.

I want to know the methods to convert a hex string to a base64 string.

I tried using this method

```
String encodedString = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(hexValue.getBytes());
```

but when I tried to convert the base64 I get the hex code instead of the string

Comment: to get string from hex use Base64.getDecoder() not getEncoder()

Comment: Why would you encode a hex string base64? You get 30% bytes more. You still have a string.

Comment: To start at the beginning: what kind of string do you have that you wanna encode hexadecimal?

Comment: `How to convert a hex code into char array in android` .... Well the char array is missing in your post....